# Detach some files into a separate Git repository

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I know there is a big thread [Detach subdirectory into separate Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository) but there are always some variations. My task differentiates from the above question is that there are some files instead of a subdirectory.

Ex.

```
XYZ/
    .git/
    XY1/
    ABC/foo.py
    ABC/bar.py
    ABC/asdf.py
    ABC/...
```

And I would like to extract *foo.py* and *bar.py* into a separate Git repository.

My first trial is to make a subdirectory for these 2 files and make use of method mentioned in [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository):

```
$ mkdir foobar
$ git mv ABC/foo.py ABC/bar.py foobar
$ git commit -m '...'
$ git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter foobar HEAD
```

So far so good except the commit history is lost. Any idea for that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [the subtree merge strategy](http://schacon.github.com/git/howto/using-merge-subtree.html) to merge the "distant" folder "ABC" into your local folder "ABC" and maintain history. Then you will use filter-branch to remove unwanted files.

Answer (score 0):

What I did to accomplish this was:

1. `git clone ABC/ DEF/; cd DEF`
2. `git remote rm origin`
3. `git filter-branch --prune-empty --tree-filter 'rm -fr <list of files/folders to remove>' -- --all`
4. `git filter-branch -f --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter DEF -- --all`

And that was it. Added new project remote, and continued working in separate repository.